# Is it possible to loop through all objects in an interface to get key and value?

Tags: typescript, angular

I built an interface that accepts all potential search criteria and then passing it to a service that will put all the values into the service url.  Is it possible to loop through all the objects in the interface and am I able to  retrieve both the key and value? I was initially writing a long `if ... else if ...` statement (Sample below.)  I'm not sure if I'm going about this in the best way

Interface:

```
export interface ILegislatorSearchCriteria {
    all_legislators?: string;
    in_office?: string; // true false
    party?: string; // 'R', 'D', or 'I'
    gender?: string; // 'M' or 'F'
    state?: string; // Two letter code
    ...
}
```

Service:

```
getLegislators(crit: ILegislatorSearchCriteria): Observable<ILegislator[]> {
    let serviceUrl = this._legislatorUrl;

    if (crit.all_legislators !== null) {
        serviceUrl += '&all_legislators=' + crit.all_legislators;
    } else if (crit.in_office !== null) {
        serviceUrl += '&in_office=' + crit.all_legislators;
    } else if (crit.party) {
        serviceUrl += '&party=' + crit.party;
    } else if (crit.gender) {
        serviceUrl += '&gender=' + crit.gender;
    }  ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no interfaces at runtime. They exist only for static analysis. You can get the keys of the concrete instance that you have at runtime using `Object.keys()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Ah, that stupid MDN site. Just because I'm from Austria is no reason to provide the German site by default ;-) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: But if your tring to sanitize input from XHR or the such, to make it fit an interface, this doesnt help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Using object.keys on a known data object is fine, but if you are using it on one that came from another source, eg XHR request to web server, you want to ensure all the fields in the interface are present you have to keep a list of all the properties somewhere, as well as the interface itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use a regular class instead of an interface for thus case?

Comment: I had not thought about doing this, obviously the class must have initial values for all properties. Could be a neat trick, plus it provide some sensible default values.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Brilliant!